# How to interprete the Python Clustering scores?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, metrics, unsupervised-learning

I try to use Agglomerative Clustering to cluster some Data but i dont know which number of clusters are perfect. Here are my results:[image: Graph shows lot of Measuring Values in percentage on y axis and the number of Clusters on x axis]

The Database consists out of 65 Classes to be recognize. Gini Value=0.265.

1. What should be choosen for number of clusters? Maybe the same as number of classes?
2. What means the intersection point of completeness and homogeneity and v measure?
3. What means the maximum in adjusted mutual info score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use these measures for choosing k. Because they compare to the known solution. If you have a known solution, why choose an approximation instead?
2. Probably just a coincidence. But you may want to study the equations, maybe they do agree at this point.
3. For AMI, NMI, ARI, etc. the maximum is the k with the largest agreement with your existing labeled solution.